# How to dynamically calculate height of UITableViewCell according to device

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a `UITableViewController` now, and I have x cells for `UITableView`, which is the same height with screen. I don't want to scroll the `UITableView`, and I want to divide whole screen into x parts with the same height.

Do I have to check device type first, then calculate height of every cell? Then there are lots of `if` or `switch` statement. What the best way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you have a Navigation Bar, try this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height
    return (screenHeight - 64) / <number of cells>
}
```

If you don't have Nagivation Bar, just replace

`return (screenHeight - 64) / <number of cells>`

with

`return screenHeight / <number of cells>`